# Disable an option of multiple select options

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have a  multiple select option in BootStrap and I want if user selects option value=1, then they cannot choose option with value=5 and vice versa

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please paste relevant HTML and CSS and script into the panes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this. It was not trivial

Remember JS numbers arrays and collections from 0, but I store the values in the selected array

```js
const pairs = [, 5, 6, , 1]; // 1=5, 2=6 5:1
$(function() {
  $(".selectpicker").selectpicker()
  $(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    // const selected = $("option:selected", this).map((i, ele) => ele.value).get();
    $("option", this).prop("disabled", false); // enable all
    $("option:selected", this).each(function() { // disable selected pair
      const paired = pairs[$(this).val()];
      if (paired) {
        // if value i is among the selected, disable value pairs[i]
        console.log("value", this.value, "disable", paired)
        $(".selectpicker").find('option[value=' + paired + ']')
          .prop("selected", false)
          .prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
    // refresh the select
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<select id="sel1" class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide ,if I use it for value=2 and value=6 it does not work ,you know, value=1 opposed of value=5 , value=2 opposed of value=6 , value=3 opposed of value=4

Comment: I do not understand. You can disable all selects in pairs just know you have to disable index 1 to disable value 2. -

Comment: you know when I am put this code $(".selectpicker").find('option').eq(5).prop("disabled", selected.indexOf("2") != 1); , when I choose value 1 both value 5 and 6 become disabled

Comment: This is SUPER tricky. What happens if I select 1 (disable 5) and then click 4 (disable 1) Should I then ENABLE 5 again? My code will do that now but you have to deselect 4 again to get 5 enabled.